# how to get running total column

Tags: sql, derby

sir i have query that show RUNNING TOTAL but not show me exect Dr_amount and Cr_amount as per transaction how to get Dr_amount and Cr_amount as per single transaction

```
SELECT 
V_DATE,FLAG,V_NUM,V_NARATION,
sum(DR_AMOUNT) AS DEBIT,
sum(CR_AMOUNT) AS CRIDIT,
sum(dr_amount)-sum(cr_amount) as total
FROM VOUCHARDETAIL AS VDTL
INNER JOIN VOUCHARMASTER AS VMST
ON VDTL.DTL_NUM <=VMST.MST_NUM
WHERE (V_DATE BETWEEN '12-03-2017' AND '13-03-2017') AND (FLAG='IV' OR FLAG='BR'
OR FLAG='CP' OR FLAG='CR' OR FLAG='JV') AND (AC_CODE=60030002) 
GROUP BY
V_DATE,FLAG,V_NUM,V_NARATION
ORDER BY
V_DATE
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qORcF.png)

Comment: Plese include sample desired output.

Comment: Supporting these "OLAP" query types has been a long-standing request of the Derby community that hasn't found many contributors willing to work on it: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/OLAPOperations